# Excel Formula to highland entire row if date in one field exceeds 6 months?

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to work out a formula that will allow me to highland an entire row should a specific date on one field of that row exceed 6 months. The reason for this is to be able to visually see lists of contacts I haven't been in touch with for 6 months as a reminder.

I go to "conditional formatting", and then "use a formula to determine which cells to format", and type in "=F37

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a formula ?

Comment: Pretty much. Just a simple formula that would allow an entire row highlighted a certain colour based on a 'due date' exceeding a 6 month period or 180 days or whatever is the easiest method on excel

Answer (score 2):

You mean more than 6 months in the past?

To format whole row then select whole range of data and, assuming data starts at row 2, use this formula in CF

```
=AND($F2< EDATE(TODAY(),-6),$F2<>"")
```

Adjust for start row of data

Make sure to include `$` before the column letter, this is what makes it format the whole row

Comment: That's correct. any date that is past 6 months in the past, so any date prior to July 17. I tried that formula but it either turns the entire row yellow before I enter anything into the field or the individual cell itself turning yellow. What I did was select (for example) A29 and highlight A29 to F29, then entered in your formula =$F29< EDATE(TODAY(),-6) (both with the space and without the space before the EDATE) on the conditional formatting box "use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Comment: Ok, yes, blank cells will be formatted, you can change formula to stop that, see my edit: so if the date is in F29, that should work for you......you can select a multi-row range, too, just apply the formula for first row

Comment: Btw you don't need the space in the formula - I needed to add that here to make the formula display correctly

Comment: Thanks. Used this on another row to test, and worked without the blanks too, which is even better;   =AND($A148<EDATE(TODAY(),-6),$F148<>"")

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, a formula in a conditional format is right. You just need to use the right formula and anchor the column ($)
So in your example,

1) select the row

2) add conditional format

3) select formula option

4) add following formula

```
=If($F37<EDATE(TODAY(),-6,true,false) )
```

5) set format of the conditional format

Comment: Almost, remove the " as thats just for text. Also this would only work if first row you selected was 37. If you wanted to do row 1 to 37. Select the rows and do 

=IF($F1<EDATE(TODAY(),-6,true,false)

And this would then work on cells F1 to F37